# Rewrite outgoing http responses to https

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm faced with the task of rewriting some http communication to https. My infrastructure looks like this:

Internet <--> Apache Webserver <--> JBoss AS

My apache already redirects everything to https. But my JBoss is not responding https-only. So the browser always answers like this "You're accessing a secure website but not everything is delivered securely. Do you want to loak unsecure contents as well?" and the site looks crippled.

So what I want to do is rewrite every http answer from my jboss to https. I'd like to not change my jboss config too much so I'm trying to achieve that through some apache settings. But I'm don't really have an idea how. A simple rewrite rule like this has no effect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

My apache modules of choise are mod_rewrite and mod_proxy_ajp.

I'd really apprechiate any hint pointing in the right direction.
Regards Sebastian

Comment: Don't think a rewrite rule will help here because it sounds your JBoss server is building the links that contain the URLs. You need to change the code to update the addresses. If you can't do that you might be able to use [mod_substitute](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_substitute.html) or similar

Comment: So the mod_rewrite approach is not correct and I need to make sure the jboss itself serves https? Or I could try another apache approach using mod_subsitute?